# open html with css in ms word 2010

Tags: javascript, html, css, ms-word

how can I open a html file like this one http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/cheat.html in ms word 2010 keeping the same formatting and spacing? I tried taking out the images and javascript but did not work and it left aligns all the text and tables are gone.

Here is version without javascript or images

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

That file isn't just HTML and CSS; it contains a vast quantity of sophisticated Javascript code that displays a PDF in a web page. Even as displayed, many parts of the document (including table borders and fraction bars) are dynamically rendered as large transparent images.

There is absolutely no way to convert that into a Word document. It's quite possible that some of the equations in the document cannot be rendered in a Word document at all, even manually. If you want the TeX source for the document, it's available online at:

https://web.cs.ship.edu/~tbriggs/cheatsheet/index.html

Comment: like I said I took out all the javascript code and images so my version is only html and css. Quite easy to do that part but even afterwards the text wont display properly formatted and spacing.

Comment: You're right; it won't display correctly. The results of this Javascript PDF renderer are not intended to be displayed by anything other than a web browser. If you want a Word version of this document, you'll need to make one yourself.